# Boost Library Format; getting std::string

Tags: c++, boost

I want to add some string which I format using the boost library as follows

```
boost::container::vector<std::string> someStringVector;
someStringVector.push_back(
    format("after is x:%f y:%f and before is x:%f y:%f\r\n") % 
    temp.x %
    temp.y %
    this->body->GetPosition().x %
    this->body->GetPosition().y;
```

The compiler is complaining that it can't convert types, and I tried appending .str() to the end of what format returns, but it still complained.

The error message I got was:

```
error C2664: 'void boost::container::vector<T>::push_back(
  const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' :
  cannot convert parameter 1 from
    'boost::basic_format<Ch>' to 
    'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
```

Anyone have some insight?

Comment: When the compiler complains, it usually does so in the form of error messages.  What error messages does it give you?

Comment: How about wrapping call to boost::format in boost::str?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to wrap the format in a call to boost::str, like so:

```
str( format("after is x:%f y:%f and before is x:%f y:%f\r\n")
     % temp.x % temp.y % this->body->GetPosition().x % this->body->GetPosition().y)
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me the error: error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&'

Comment: @moowiz2020: What type is someStringArray?  The full type specification, including template parameters.

Comment: it's a boost::container::vector<std::string>.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a ".str()" to the resulting format object should be enough (and works for me). It is not clear from your question exactly how you did so, but I did notice that your example is missing the closing parens on the push_back().

Note that you want to call str() on the format object returned from the last % operator, the easiest way to do so is to just wrap the whole format line in parens like so:

```
boost::container::vector<std::string> someStringVector;
someStringVector.push_back(
    (format("after is x:%f y:%f and before is x:%f y:%f\r\n") % 
    temp.x %
    temp.y %
    this->body->GetPosition().x %
    this->body->GetPosition().y).str() );
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into the program at that point, and it gives me the error: error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&'. It might be a compiler specific issue

Comment: @moowiz2020: I used VS 2008. Perhaps you need to supply a complete sample that exhibits the problem.